# PostgreSQL query not working as intended

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a view which has a simple query

`create or replace view temp(EFTSLOAD, UOC, CODE) as`

`select eftsload, uoc,code from subjects where`

`cast (eftsload as numeric(5,3))  != cast((uoc/48) as numeric(5,3));`

But my query select * from temp; gives me rows like

`eftsload      |      uoc     |    code`

`0.125               6          ECONXXXX`

`0.5                 24         HISTXXXX`

The condition says eftsload != uoc/48 but I get rows where efts = 0.125 and uoc =6 which a violation as 6/48=0.125 and many other instances where the relation eftsload != uoc/48 is clearly not true

Why does this happen?

Comment: I can't read that text... Formatted text please, not images.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: eftslaod in definition and efts in columns.

Comment: did not know that I couldnt use images
Thanks. I hope this is suficient to understand my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that the quantity `uoc/48` is being treated as integer division, and then afterwards the truncated quotient is being cast to a numeric floating point.  But you really want to do floating point division here.

Try this:

```
select eftsload, uoc, code
from subjects
where cast(eftsload as numeric(5,3)) != uoc / 48::numeric(5,3)
```

Comment: That's it. Its not giving me those values anymore.
Thanks!